# How to have a read more text on one row only

Tags: html, css

I have a text that may not be more than 12 characters long
and if it is a read read more text should be shown.

for instance "this is a te...read more".

This felt like an easy task, the problem is that the text may only be
on one row and is not allowed to be multiple rows.

If the width is smaller the text should auto size and could be less than 12 characters.
for instance: "this is...read more".

At first it felt like an easy task but now I'm very confused on how this can be archived.

What I've managed to find so far is that I can put the div like this in order for it to stay on one row
if the text is short enough:

```
<div style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;">
<span>this is a test text</span>
</div>
<div>
<span>read more</span>
</div>
```

Any help or input is highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: take a look [ellipsis](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/)

Comment: Ye i have but, not sure on how to keep in on one row

Comment: Could you provide any feedback, should I modify my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should add width or max-width if possible.

### Option 1:

```css
.preview{
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.more{
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="preview">this is a test text</span>
  <span class="more">read more</span>
</div>
```

### Option 2:

Use the [after pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after):

```css
.container::after{
  content: 'read more';
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.preview{
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="preview">this is a test text</span>
</div>
```

### Option 3:

Try:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
```

I hope it helps!

### Bonus:

You can use `ch` as the width, which is the "character unit".

> The advance measure (width) of the glyph "0" of the element's font. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units)

Example:

```
width: 12ch;
```